# How use parameters/variable and explain together

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, pgadmin, sql-execution-plan

I have my function with one parameter `carAzimuth`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map.get_near_link(x numeric, y numeric, carAzimuth numeric)
```

Inside I have some calculation and this query

```
SELECT *
FROM map.vzla_seg S
WHERE
    S.azimuth > carAzimuth - 30  and   
    S.azimuth < carAzimuth + 30  or
    S.azimuth < carAzimuth - 330 or 
    S.azimuth > carAzimuth + 330;
```

I want analyze the query performace. So I have to replace the variable for a constant. And works OK, and `EXPLAIN PLAN` show me is using the proper index.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE    
 SELECT *
 FROM map.vzla_seg S
 WHERE
    S.azimuth > 345 - 30  and   
    S.azimuth < 345 + 30  or
    S.azimuth < 345 - 330 or 
    S.azimuth > 345 + 330;
```

But is troublesome change each variable if want test different values. Then if you try

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE  
  WITH param(carAzimuth) as (select 345) 
  SELECT *
  FROM vzla_seg S, param 
  WHERE
      S.azimuth > carAzimuth- 30 and   
      S.azimuth < carAzimuth + 30 or
      S.azimuth < carAzimuth - 330 or 
      S.azimuth > carAzimuth + 330;
```

Works but stop using the index and change for `FULL SCAN`

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.01..208990.91 rows=2328905 width=4) (actual time=0.146..4138.882 rows=642115 loops=1)"
"  Join Filter: (((s.azimuth > (p.carazimuth - 30)) AND (s.azimuth < (p.carazimuth + 30))) OR (s.azimuth < (p.carazimuth - 330)) OR (s.azimuth > (p.carazimuth + 330)))"
"  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3207719"
"  CTE parameter"
"    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  CTE Scan on parameter p  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on vzla_seg s  (cost=0.00..93496.22 rows=3849822 width=4) (actual time=0.072..1380.356 rows=3849834 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 4253.113 ms"
```

So is there a way I can create my variable and use it on the explain without having a function?

Im using the SQL editor on pgAdmin to run my queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption so `WITH` clause is equivalent function is wrong. Clause `WITH` is related to [*Common Table Expressions*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) and has zero relations to functions. When you would to see plans from functions, there are two possibilities:

1. using a [*auto_explain*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) extension - with this extension you can log any nested plans - just enable a option `auto_explain.log_nested_statements`
2. you can use a prepared statements - any SQL is translated transparently to prepared statement in PLpgSQL.

   ```
   prepare xx(int) as select * from foo where a = $1::text;
   explain analyze execute xx(10);
   ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                          QUERY PLAN                                           │
   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
   │ Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..21.00 rows=4 width=64) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=0 loops=1) │
   │   Filter: (a = '10'::text)                                                                   │
   │   Rows Removed by Filter: 2                                                                   │
   │ Execution time: 0.052 ms                                                                      │
   └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
   ```

   Attention: first 5 executions the plan is always fresh (is not reused, and it is generated again and again). After 5 execution, the plan can be generic and reused. See Plan Caching chapter in [related documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/plpgsql-implementation.html).

Comment: Second option looks great, I try it that one but put the explain plan as the first line and didnt work. Now will check the nested plan.

Comment: I try `auto_explain`  example in the link and nothing happen. I set every variable to true,  any idea what Im missing?

Comment: Did you check postgresql log? Did you restart postgres (if you load auto_explain via shared_preload_libraries)?

Comment: ohh didnt check log, tought would display it on the pg_admin console